# Why was this question downvoted without even telling me why and no answers?

Tags: discussion, voting

So I just posted a question about different gun types in Fortnite BR [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/332139/differences-between-different-gun-types-normal-tactical-pump-in-fortnite) . Now it has 2 downvotes, with no comments (Other than me asking why it's downvoted) no answers in just like 30 mins. I don't understand why it was downvoted.

**First question:**

***Why*** is it downvoted?  The users who downvoted didn't explain why?

**Second question:**

Why would anyone downvote and leave without even telling me why? This can't be revenge since I've never downvoted before as I don't have enough rep.

Comment: I think I understood what you were asking (it was a little unclear), so I edited your question to try and highlight the specific question you were asking. Hopefully I captured your intent.

Answer (score 4):

It was downvoted because someone thought it lacked clarity, or it lacked research, or it wasn't useful. As to the specific reason, if no one told you (although it looks like someone tried to help you in the comments below your question), well, then instead of repeatedly asking, try looking at your question again.

Is it clearly understandable to people who aren't you? Is there anything you could make clearer, format differently, etc? (I notice you use a lot of caps and bold which aren't strictly necessary and make the question messy and hard to follow, for example).

Remember, no one has to give you a reason for their vote (people have suggested that that should be required many times in the past, and it's never gained any traction, because voting is supposed to be anonymous). Trust that if you work to write good questions, people will vote accordingly, and people will eventually try to help you, if you're open to it.

Comment: Related meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/3624389

Comment: @Dragonrage Thanks, I was looking for something like that but on MSE, never thought to check MSO. :)

Comment: No problem. I was working on a draft to answer and had the link in mine, then noticed that you had already provided an answer and it was worded better than mine.